# How to set transport in the global configuration in order to define a clustered cache - infinispan

Tags: java, jboss, infinispan, thorntail, wildfly-18

Trying to configure cache on thorntail project-defaults.yaml however am stuck with the below issue while tying to start or deploy on wildfly.

Error Must have a transport set in the global configuration in order to define a clustered cache.

Am not sure if i can resolve this through config in a standalone.xml or project-defaults yaml and or if i need to use java code.

How can i resolve this issue.

See stack trace

```
2020-03-28 17:51:11,345 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 93) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."frontend-war.war".component.CacheContainerBean.START: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."-frontend-war.war".component.CacheContainerBean.START: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentStartService$1.run(ComponentStartService.java:57)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:163)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:134)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.createInstance(BasicComponent.java:88)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponent.getComponentInstance(SingletonComponent.java:127)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponent.start(SingletonComponent.java:141)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentStartService$1.run(ComponentStartService.java:54)
    ... 8 moref
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: ISPN000343: Must have a transport set in the global configuration in order to define a clustered cache
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:246)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.requiresNew(CMTTxInterceptor.java:388)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.LifecycleCMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(LifecycleCMTTxInterceptor.java:68)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInjectionContextInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInjectionContextInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:60)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.StartupCountDownInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupCountDownInterceptor.java:25)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:161)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: ISPN000343: Must have a transport set in the global configuration in order to define a clustered cache
    at org.infinispan.configuration.cache.ClusteringConfigurationBuilder.validate(ClusteringConfigurationBuilder.java:167)
    at org.infinispan.configuration.cache.ConfigurationBuilder.validate(ConfigurationBuilder.java:271)
    at org.infinispan.configuration.cache.ConfigurationBuilder.build(ConfigurationBuilder.java:286)
    at org.infinispan.configuration.ConfigurationManager.putConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:97)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.doDefineConfiguration(DefaultCacheManager.java:396)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.defineConfiguration(DefaultCacheManager.java:355)
    at org.infinispan.manager.impl.AbstractDelegatingEmbeddedCacheManager.defineConfiguration(AbstractDelegatingEmbeddedCacheManager.java:42)
    at org.company.ox.util.CacheContainerBean.generateCache(CacheContainerBean.java:79)
    at org.company.ox.util.CacheContainerBean.init(CacheContainerBean.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.delegateInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doLifecycleInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:112)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInjectionInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceFieldInjectionInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceFieldInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceFieldInjectionInterceptorFactory.java:112)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.AroundConstructInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(AroundConstructInterceptorFactory.java:28)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInterceptorInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInterceptorInjectionInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsCreateInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsCreateInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:237)
    ... 28 more

2020-03-28 17:51:11,445 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (main) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: (("deployment" => "-frontend-war.war")) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"-frontend-war.war\".component.CacheContainerBean.START" => "java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
    Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: ISPN000343: Must have a transport set in the global configuration in order to define a clustered cache
    Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: ISPN000343: Must have a transport set in the global configuration in order to define a clustered cache"}}
2020-03-28 17:51:11,447 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (main) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "-frontend-war.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"-frontend-war.war\".component.CacheContainerBean.START" => "java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
    Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: ISPN000343: Must have a transport set in the global configuration in order to define a clustered cache
    Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: ISPN000343: Must have a transport set in the global configuration in order to define a clustered cache"}}
```

Could this be related to the fix ?

```
new GlobalConfigurationBuilder().transport().defaultTransport().build(),
```

Comment: Thorntail doesn't support clustering. Even though it's probably possible to configure it to work, you're much better off using WildFly proper.

Comment: Thanks this has saved me some work regarding Thorntail

Answer (score 2):

The below solved the issue by overriding how the cache manager.

```
 private EmbeddedCacheManager container() {
    return new DefaultCacheManager(
            new GlobalConfigurationBuilder().transport().defaultTransport().build(),
            new ConfigurationBuilder().clustering().stateTransfer().awaitInitialTransfer(false).build());
  }
```

for more see the same here https://developer.jboss.org/thread/177337